# Accessing align environment in ReactMarkdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown

Accessing align environment in ReactMarkdown.

I'd like to be able to read in markdown documents and have them render in website (I imagine I'll have to do some pre-processing so no worries if that's not entirely possible).

One of the problems I'm struggling with right now is having ReactMarkdown recognize an equation aligning environment or finding an equivalent. For example. Some gibberish I've written is

```
markdown = `The equation for a line is $y = mx +b$.
            The proof is:

            \\begin{align}
             y &= mx + b \\\\
               &= ab + c  
            \\end{align}
        `
<ReactMarkdown
   remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
   rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
   children={markdown}
/>
```

But that doesn't work...

I also tried replacing `\\begin{align}` and `\\end{align}` with `$$` and had similar results.

I've read through the [repo](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) and couldn't find anything addressing it. I also read through the plugin pages ([here](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) and [here](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-math/tree/HEAD/packages/remark-html-katex#readme)) without finding anything too promising.

Am I missing something or is there no align-like environment available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain why, but wrapping the align environment inside display mode `$$` and more importantly **importing the KaTeX stylesheet** just makes it work, at least when testing within a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) React sandbox:

```
import remarkMath from "remark-math";
import rehypeKatex from "rehype-katex";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";

const markdown = `The equation for a line is $y = mx +b$.
The proof is:

$$
\\begin{align}
 y &= mx + b \\\\
   &= ab + c  
\\end{align}
$$
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ReactMarkdown
      remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
      rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
      children={markdown}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't work in my current environment but I started a new one and made it just like that and it does... Time to dig into the weeds and figure out what's going on. I appreciate it!

Comment: @financial_physician I'm not sure what it looks like for you when you say that it doesn't work, but for me when the stylesheet is missing, I can see the raw `\begin{align}` etc. commands inside the `.katex-mathml` element, and the non-aligned `.katex-html` below that. The stylesheet just hides the `mathml` and just styles the html version. Try for example just adding the KaTeX stylesheet with a `<link>` to their CDN. Example here: https://katex.org/docs/browser.html

Comment: Yeah, I read in the stylesheet but still only saw the literal characters I put in for the align section (first equation loaded fine). My project isn't very large and this is my first time using react so redoing stuff and checking it step by step will be good learning experience. Thanks a bunch @cbr